# How to filter data using quantile?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to filter data quantile by value (95%, 90%, 85%, 80%)

| Gene | FPKM |
| --- | --- |
| A | 0.34 |
| D | 0.25 |
| C | 0.75 |
| E | 1.5 |
| B | 0.31 |
| F | 2.45 |
| Y | 7.89 |

So far this is what I have tried:

```
q = df['FPKM'].quantile([0.75,0.95])
print(q)

q95 = df[df['FPKM'].ge(q[0.95]) #95th quantile
q90 = df[df['FPKM'].between(q[.95],q[0.85])] # 90th quantile
```

Not sure if it's the right way to extract it this way...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you only have 2 quantiles, in ascending order, you can use parameter expansion:

```
q = df['FPKM'].quantile([0.75,0.95])
out = df[df['FPKM'].between(*q)]
```

Else, ensure you use the correct indices of `q`:

```
q = df['FPKM'].quantile([0.75,0.95])
df[df['FPKM'].between(q[.75], q[0.95])]
```

output:

```
  Gene  FPKM
5    F  2.45
```